# If point is inside a triangle (help when point is on the boundary of triangle)

Tags: c, geometry

The following code tests whether a point is inside a triangle or not, it does everything correctly but whenever I specify a point on the triangle's boundary it says it is outside (I want it to be inside). Can anyone figure out what's wrong? (I did not write the following code, so please I understand the style is horrible ignore it... trust me it was worse before I cleaned up).

Say if I entered triangle with vertices A(0,0) B(10,0) C(0,10) and point (5,0) it will still show up as outside the triangle!

```
#include <stdio.h>

int test2( double px, double py, double m, double b ) {    
    if (py < m * px + b ) {
        return -1; // point is under line
    }else if ( py == m * px + b ){
        return 0; // point is on line
    } else {
        return 1; // point is over line
    }
}

int test1(double px, double py, double m,double b, double lx,double ly) {     
   return (test2(px,py, m,b) == test2(lx,ly,m,b));    
}

int tritest (double x0,double y0,double x1,double y1,double x2,double y2,double px, double py) {

   int line1, line2, line3;    
   double m01 = (y1-y0)/(x1-x0);    
   double b01 = m01 * -x1 + y1;    
   double m02, m12, b02, b12;    
   m02 = (y2-y0)/(x2-x0);    
   m12 = (y2-y1)/(x2-x1);    
   b02 = m02 * -x2 + y2;    
   b12 = m12 * -x2 + y2;

   // vertical line checks

   if( x1 == x0 ) {    
      line1 = ( (px <= x0) == (x2 <= x0) );    
   } else {    
      line1 = test1( px, py, m01, b01,x2,y2);    
   }

   if( x1 == x2 ) {    
      line2 = ( (px <= x2) == (x0 <= x2) );    
   } else {    
      line2 = test1(px,py, m12, b12,x0,y0);    
   }

   if( x2 == x0 ) {    
      line3 = ( (px <= x0 ) == (x1 <= x0) );} else {    
      line3 = test1(px, py, m02,b02,x1,y1);    
   }

   return line1 && line2 && line3;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {    
   double x0,y0,x1,y1,x2,y2,px;    
   double py;    
   int scanfsReturnValueAggregatedOverAllScanfs = 0;

   // get input

   printf("Triangle Vertex A (enter x,y): "); scanfsReturnValueAggregatedOverAllScanfs += scanf("%lf,%lf", &x0,&y0);    
   printf("\nTriangle Vertex B (enter x,y): "); scanfsReturnValueAggregatedOverAllScanfs += scanf("%lf,%lf", &x1,&y1);    
   printf("\nTriangle Vertex C (enter x,y): "); scanfsReturnValueAggregatedOverAllScanfs += scanf("%lf,%lf", &x2,&y2);    
   printf("\nTest Point (enter x,y): "); scanfsReturnValueAggregatedOverAllScanfs += scanf("%lf,%lf", &px,&py);
   // print error

   if( scanfsReturnValueAggregatedOverAllScanfs != 8 ) {    
      printf("You're stup** and didn't put in the right inputs!\n");    
      return 1;    
   }

   // print answer

   printf("\nThe point is ");

   if (tritest(x0,y0,x1,y1,x2,y2,px,py)) {    
      printf("INSIDE");    
   } else {    
      printf("OUTSIDE");    
   }

   printf(" the Triangle\n");

   // return 0

   return 0;    
}
```

Comment: could you explain "point is over line" and "point is on line".

Comment: We use the point gradient equation y = mx + b to determine if the point is above the line (on side of the triangle), below or on the line.

Comment: that i already know.And i can smell that there is definitely some problem in your checking conditions.Basically by these checks you are determining whether point is to the left or right of line.But this conditions would be differennt for lines with different slopes.These checks are valid only for m>0 and m<1.

Answer (score 3):

One thing that comes up straight away for me is that you are comparing doubles using `==`.This comparison is never accurate and may produce suprising results. It is better to do something like `fabs(d1-d2) < 1e-3` to compare the doubles for equality.

Comment: I haven't learnt the fabs function (forgot to add homework tab).

Comment: Nothing special there, it just returns the absolute value of the given variable. It is declared in `math.h`.

Comment: Thanks Naveen, I should rather say I'm not allowed to use what we haven't learnt yet.

Comment: @Carpe Diem: if (py < m * px + b - 1e-3 ) { return -1; } else if (py > m * px + b + 1e-3 ) { return 1; } else { return 0; }

Answer (score 0):

```
int test2( double px, double py, double m, double b ) {

if (py < m * px + b ) {
    return -1; 
}else if ( py == m * px + b ){
    return 0;  //Should be return 1 as point is on line.Thus inside the triangle
} else {
    return 1; //should be return 0 as point is outside this line
}
}
```

I think there is problem in return values that you are returning in above method.These conditions would be different for lines with different slopes.These checks are valid only for m>0 and m<1.And your code is running well because of a **fluke** .Test Your code for lines with different slopes.

Comment: Nope, nothing still. I'm concerned about what the tritest function returns... "return line1 && line2 && line3;" how does it return 3 values? What happens then @Algorithmist ?

Comment: @Carpe could you clarify your saying.

Comment: `return line1 && line2 && line3;` What does this do? Can you give an example of what it will return?

Comment: The return keyword will return only one item. The "line1 && line2 && line3" represent a logical AND operation performed on the three "line" values.  Thus, tritest will return a 0 if the condition is false, and 1 (true) otherwise.